# How can I select group by values in specific propoerty?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using a group by select using entity framework core and linq.

```
var list = context.Ways.GroupBY(s=>s.Type).Select(w=> new {
    type = w.key,
    total = (int)w.Sum(b => b.Length)
})
```

This giwes me a list.

```
type        total
T1          2541
T2          5481
T5          4
T9          2
T11         856
T3          25
```

So I want to group into "Others", if total is smaller than 100 like following,

```
type        total
T1          2541
T2          5481
T11         856
OTHERS      31
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a second group by

```
var list = context.Ways.GroupBy(s => s.Type).Select(w => new
{
    type = w.Key,
    total = (int)w.Sum(b => b.Length)
}).GroupBy(s => s.total < 100 ? "Others" : s.type)
.Select(w => new
{
    type = w.Key,
    total = (int)w.Sum(b => b.total)
});
```

Comment: But you selected Length <100, I need sum of lengths <100

Comment: Updated to use a second `GroupBy`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Entity Framework, but you can write a method to iterate over the list in memory. For example, assuming you have a class to hold the key and value like this (or you could rewrite using `KeyValuePair` or a tuple):

```
public class ItemCount
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

An extension method to aggregate the smaller values could look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<ItemCount> AggregateWithThreshold(this IEnumerable<ItemCount> source, 
    int threshold)
{
    // The total item to return
    var total = new ItemCount
    {
        Name = "Others",
        Count = 0
    };

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (item.Count >= threshold)
        {
            // If count is above threshold, just return the value
            yield return item;
        }
        else
        {
            // Keep the total count
            total.Count += item.Count;
        }
    }

    // No need to return a zero count if all values were above the threshold
    if(total.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return total;
    }

}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
var list = context.Ways
    .GroupBY(s => s.Type)
    .Select(w => new ItemCount // Note we are using the new class here
    {
        Name = w.key,
        Count = (int)w.Sum(b => b.Length)
    });

var result = list.AggregateWithThreshold(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can add additional operation that would calculate the `Others` value based on 2 collection values you have already. Like this:

```
var list = context.Ways.GroupBy(s=>s.Type).Select(w=> new {
    type = w.key,
    total = (int)w.Sum(b => b.Length)
});

var totalSum = context.Ways.Sum(x => x.Length);
var listSum = list.Sum(x => x.total);

list.Add(new {
    type = "Others",
    total = totalSum - listSum
});
```